# Is Fuegoleon Vermillion as powerful as the magic emperor?

Tags: black-clover

The stats for Julius Novachrono and Fuegoleon Vermillion in the Black Clover Wikia are identical. 4 in physical strenght, 5 in amount of magic, 5 in magic control, 4 in magic sensing and 5 in cleverness.

[Julius Novachrono](https://blackclover.fandom.com/wiki/Julius_Novachrono)

[Fuegoleon Vermillion](https://blackclover.fandom.com/wiki/Fuegoleon_Vermillion)

Are they supposed to be equally powerful or are there other aspects that constitues power in Black Clover?